# A Problem when trying to access to specific JSON data using map in React.js

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, reactjs, dictionary

I can not read data from JSON. I checked that the data is stored in the component state from console after the component get mounted. In the return statement, I tried to render the url string from JSON data using map method. When I log the data information from the console, the data can be found in 'this.state.data' or 'elm' but when add 'multimedia[idx]' to the end of it, it says can not find the data. I want to know the reason of it.

```js
this.state.data.map((elm, idx) =>
//...
<div>{elm.multimedia[idx].url}</div>
//...
```

JSON data shape of multidmedia element logged from the console:

```js
(29) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, undefined, {…}]

0:{
  caption: "string",
  copyright: "string",
  format: "mediumThreeByTwo210",
  height: 140,
  subtype: "photo",
  type: "image",
  url: "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/02/05/science/05SCI-ZIMMER1/05SCI-ZIMMER1-mediumThreeByTwo210.jpg",
  width: 210
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

The reason why it cannot read from the the `multimedia` property is because you are trying to access the `multimedia` property by using an index generated from the `this.state.data` property. Therefore, it may be that your current index is greater than the items inside the `multimedia` array.

## Explanation

So, if you have for example...

```
this.state.data = [
  {multimedia: [{}, {}, {}]},
  {multimedia: [{}, {}, {}]},
  {multimedia: [{}, {}]},
]
```

Your map will start looking at the first element in the data array, and passing that as the `elm` variable will be populated with the first element, and so on... but when accessing the 3rd element in the `data` array, you will get an object with only 2 items in the `multimedia` array, but since you're accessing the 3rd element of `this.state.data`, your `idx` variable will be set to `2`, and when trying to access `elm.multimedia[idx].url` it will fail because `elm.multimedia[2]` it's undefined for the 3rd element.

Comment: Your answer is close to the solution. the problems was, there was an undefined element among those 29 element. so when the map methods tried accessed to the element, It ended up in generating error event thought other 28 elements were okay. thank you for your help :)

Comment: I'm glad that it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see from your data, it looks like your `data` has an attribute `multimedia` which contains the array of the objects with the shape that you posted.

So in this case, your code should be something like:

```
this.state.data.multimedia.map((elm, idx) =>
//...
<div>{elm.url}</div>
```

Otherwise, if your `data` is already the array of those objects, you can do directly something like:

```
this.state.data.map((elm, idx) =>
//...
<div>{elm.url}</div>
```